# Symfony2 controller return back to form input with field value

Tags: forms, symfony, controller

Is it possible to return "nothing" in Controller?

For example:

Here is my index.html.twig

```
<form ... action="{{ path('login') }}">
  <input type="password" name="pwd" > with field value
  ...
</form>
```

here is my Controller

```
...
if (count($errors) != 0) {
  Now I want to return back to my form with refill input.
}
```

Comment: for return nothing in controller `return new Response();`

Comment: to redirect you can use return `$this-redirect('url');`

Comment: I think useful for you would be trying this command "doctrine:generate:crud", read here http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html